# ansible roles. Is there a way to make directory structure more concise?

Tags: ansible

Now my directory structure looks like:

```
roles
├── python2
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
└── redis
    ├── handlers
    │   └── main.yml
    └── tasks
        └── main.yml
```

Which is a little bit overcomplicated. Is there a way to make it like?

```
roles
├── python2
│   └── tasks.yml
└── redis
    ├── tasks.yml
    └── handlers.yml
```

I checked a documentation and it's look like there is no such option.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there isn't a way to do this with *roles*, but it sounds like you may not need roles at all for this. You could instead use includes. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html

Your file structure could look like one of the following:

```
main.yml
includes
├── python2
│   └── tasks.yml
└── redis
    ├── tasks.yml
    └── handlers.yml
```

or

```
main.yml
python2Tasks.yml
redisTasks.yml
redisHandlers.yml
```

or

```
main.yml
tasks
├── python2.yml
└── redis.yml
handlers
└── redis.yml
```

main.yml would look something like:

```
- name: python2 play
  hosts: python2Hosts
  tasks:
    - include: includes/python2/tasks.yml

- name: redis play
  hosts: redisHosts
  tasks:
    - include: includes/redis/tasks.yml
  handlers:
    - include: includes/redis/handlers.yml
```